# NumericTextBox Loses Value using Html.TextBoxFor, not HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

When I use the Kendo UI Core widget with Html.TextBoxFor (for numeric textbox editing, specifically to enter a dollar amount) like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.TotalAmount, new { @class = "currency-editor", min = "0", })
```

On posting back and processing the data, the value posts back as null, and thus server-side code checking done in the controller fails because nothing posts back.

When I use Raw HTML like:

```
<input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(i => i.TotalAmount)" name="@Html.IdFor(i => i.TotalAmount)" value="@Model.TotalAmount"
       class="currency-editor" min="0" />
```

It works just fine.  I don't know what the difference is?  The initialization plugin (which initializes with no problems) is:

```
$(".currency-editor").kendoNumericTextBox({
            format: "c2",
            decimals: 2,
            spinners: false
         });
```

Obviously it appears something internally with the TextBoxFor plugin, maybe validation specific?  MVC 5, 2015 Q3 Kendo UI Core (free version).

Comment: When you disable the  kendo plugin code and use TextBoxFor, is it working ?

Comment: Yeah it would.   I figured it out, it did have to do with validation... I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with input-validation-error and the widget being hidden - the one step I didn't put together was that this field was being validated and this added to the tag output.  The trick was (as noted in Telerik's documentation):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    //omitted for brevity
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".k-widget").removeClass("input-validation-error");
    });
</script>
```

Referenced here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/validation#the-widgets-are-hidden-after-a-postback-when-using-the-jquery-validation

Answer (score 0):

can you please try like this

```
<script>
    $(".currency-editor").kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "c2",
        decimals: 2,
        spinners: false,
        value : @Model.TotalAmount
     });
```